# Wireshark what do the dots mean in message?

Tags: tcp, padding, wireshark

In wireshark I get several dots before and after a tcp message like so:

```
.................................
```

Each 4 dots is colored differently (orange and blue)

Im wondering what these mean? I am padding each 4 bytes with zeros. x00 , so im wondering is the orange part the padding?

Comment: Is this in "Follow TCP Stream"?

Comment: I think it would have to be "Follow TCP Stream" based on the coloring. If it is, those different colors represent different sides of the TCP connection. Jerry_Y's answer below explains why they are dots. Flip it over to hex dump to see the actual data.

Answer (score 4):

Wireshark trying to treate the hex as ASCII and print it.

But in ASCII only `0x20 ~ 0x7E is printable`, other hex would be displayed as `...`

Have no idea about the color thing.